# mongodb 2.6.3 use wrong index

Tags: mongodb-indexes

I have a query like below.Obviously the better index is "platform_1_keyuserAccountID_1_weiboAccountID_1_postTime_1",but mongodb choose "weiboAccountID_1",am i make something wrong?

```
db.inbox_weibo.find({platform: "sina", keyuserAccountID:"1665337047", weiboAccountID: "2271338624"}).explain(true);
```

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor weiboAccountID_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 24,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 634425,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 1,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 2912,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "weiboAccountID" : [
            [
                "2271338624",
                "2271338624"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "allPlans" : [
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor weiboAccountID_1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 1,
            "nscannedObjects" : 1,
            "nscanned" : 1,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "weiboAccountID" : [
                    [
                        "2271338624",
                        "2271338624"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor platform_1_keyuserAccountID_1_dealed_1_operatorID_1_weiboAccountID_1_postTIme_-1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 1,
            "nscannedObjects" : 1,
            "nscanned" : 62,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "platform" : [
                    [
                        "sina",
                        "sina"
                    ]
                ],
                "keyuserAccountID" : [
                    [
                        "1665337047",
                        "1665337047"
                    ]
                ],
                "dealed" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "operatorID" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "weiboAccountID" : [
                    [
                        "2271338624",
                        "2271338624"
                    ]
                ],
                "postTIme" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor platform_1_keyuserAccountID_1_weiboAccountID_1_postTime_-1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 1,
            "nscannedObjects" : 1,
            "nscanned" : 1,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "platform" : [
                    [
                        "sina",
                        "sina"
                    ]
                ],
                "keyuserAccountID" : [
                    [
                        "1665337047",
                        "1665337047"
                    ]
                ],
                "weiboAccountID" : [
                    [
                        "2271338624",
                        "2271338624"
                    ]
                ],
                "postTime" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor platform_keyuserAccountID_dealed_postTime_weiboAccountID",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 1,
            "nscannedObjects" : 1,
            "nscanned" : 634331,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "platform" : [
                    [
                        "sina",
                        "sina"
                    ]
                ],
                "keyuserAccountID" : [
                    [
                        "1665337047",
                        "1665337047"
                    ]
                ],
                "dealed" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "postTime" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "weiboAccountID" : [
                    [
                        "2271338624",
                        "2271338624"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor platform_1_keyuserAccountID_1_mid_1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 0,
            "nscannedObjects" : 2,
            "nscanned" : 3,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "platform" : [
                    [
                        "sina",
                        "sina"
                    ]
                ],
                "keyuserAccountID" : [
                    [
                        "1665337047",
                        "1665337047"
                    ]
                ],
                "mid" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor platform_1_keyuserAccountID_1_dealerID_1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 0,
            "nscannedObjects" : 2,
            "nscanned" : 3,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "platform" : [
                    [
                        "sina",
                        "sina"
                    ]
                ],
                "keyuserAccountID" : [
                    [
                        "1665337047",
                        "1665337047"
                    ]
                ],
                "dealerID" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor distinctAccountAgg",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 0,
            "nscannedObjects" : 2,
            "nscanned" : 3,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "platform" : [
                    [
                        "sina",
                        "sina"
                    ]
                ],
                "keyuserAccountID" : [
                    [
                        "1665337047",
                        "1665337047"
                    ]
                ],
                "dealed" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "operatorID" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "postTime" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor fansCountUndealed",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 0,
            "nscannedObjects" : 2,
            "nscanned" : 3,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "platform" : [
                    [
                        "sina",
                        "sina"
                    ]
                ],
                "keyuserAccountID" : [
                    [
                        "1665337047",
                        "1665337047"
                    ]
                ],
                "dealed" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "fromType" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "fansCount" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "postTime" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "usePicture" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor retweetCountUndealed",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 0,
            "nscannedObjects" : 2,
            "nscanned" : 3,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "platform" : [
                    [
                        "sina",
                        "sina"
                    ]
                ],
                "keyuserAccountID" : [
                    [
                        "1665337047",
                        "1665337047"
                    ]
                ],
                "dealed" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "fromType" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "sourceRetweetCount" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "postTime" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "usePicture" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor interactUndealed",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 0,
            "nscannedObjects" : 2,
            "nscanned" : 3,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "platform" : [
                    [
                        "sina",
                        "sina"
                    ]
                ],
                "keyuserAccountID" : [
                    [
                        "1665337047",
                        "1665337047"
                    ]
                ],
                "dealed" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "fromType" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "userInteractionCount" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "postTime" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "usePicture" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor platform_1_keyuserAccountID_1_dealed_1_dealTime_-1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 0,
            "nscannedObjects" : 2,
            "nscanned" : 3,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "platform" : [
                    [
                        "sina",
                        "sina"
                    ]
                ],
                "keyuserAccountID" : [
                    [
                        "1665337047",
                        "1665337047"
                    ]
                ],
                "dealed" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "dealTime" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor platform_1_keyuserAccountID_1_dealerID_1_postTime_-1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 0,
            "nscannedObjects" : 2,
            "nscanned" : 3,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "platform" : [
                    [
                        "sina",
                        "sina"
                    ]
                ],
                "keyuserAccountID" : [
                    [
                        "1665337047",
                        "1665337047"
                    ]
                ],
                "dealerID" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "postTime" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor platform_1_keyuserAccountID_1_postTime_-1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 0,
            "nscannedObjects" : 2,
            "nscanned" : 3,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "platform" : [
                    [
                        "sina",
                        "sina"
                    ]
                ],
                "keyuserAccountID" : [
                    [
                        "1665337047",
                        "1665337047"
                    ]
                ],
                "postTime" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "cursor" : "BtreeCursor keyuserAccountID_dealed_createTime_-1",
            "isMultiKey" : false,
            "n" : 0,
            "nscannedObjects" : 2,
            "nscanned" : 3,
            "scanAndOrder" : false,
            "indexOnly" : false,
            "nChunkSkips" : 0,
            "indexBounds" : {
                "keyuserAccountID" : [
                    [
                        "1665337047",
                        "1665337047"
                    ]
                ],
                "dealed" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ],
                "createTime" : [
                    [
                        {
                            "$maxElement" : 1
                        },
                        {
                            "$minElement" : 1
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the other index is "better". It seems that both indexes (the one you would suggest and the one mongodb uses) return the queried object with "nscanned:1", so they are equally perfect for this query. I say that since "weiboAccountID" in your test dataset defines exactly the one record you are looking for, there is no need for other indexes in this case - mongodb will choose the first good fit. Try adding more records with this same exact weiboAccountID (if duplicated Ids are at all valid in your dataset) and re-run the query, see how it changes the execution.